# If I know the input and the output of a function, is there a way I can make a program to approximate the code of the function

Tags: python

I am thinking of sha256 as an example. When one puts characters in, one gets a hash and one already know what the input is. If I have those two things can a program guess the function that sha256 uses for example to turn the input into the output?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Not without making stuff more complicated than you want it to be.

Long answer: Yes, kind of.

"Guessing" what to do to inputs to get desired outputs is the main idea of neural networks. This is why called "function approximators". The problem with using neural networks is that they're usually more complicated than just figuring out an algorithm to get what you want. There are libraries to help with this, such as TensorFlow, but it's still complicated. Also, while neural networks can approximate a function, they don't write any code. For this reason, they don't fulfill what your question is asking. Neural networks shine when you're trying to model something with a lot of inputs and outputs and their relationship is very complex, such as classifying images or generating text.